# Calculate the convolution of probability distributions

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, convolution

**Question:**

Given independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, and the corresponding density functions are $f_X(x)= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \text{, } x \in [0,1]$ and $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} \text{, } y \in [0,1]$. If $S=X+Y$, calculate $P(S \leq 1)$.

**What I've tried:**

Using [convolution probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) rules, we have:

$$f_S(s) = \int \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{s-t}}dt=?$$

I am not sure about the supports of this integral? By looking at density functions of $X$ and $Y$, we know that $x,y \in [0,1]$, does that imply the supports of $f_S$ are $0,1$, that is, $\int_0^1$?

Also, how to solve such integral? I know how to solve $\int \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}dt$, but have never deal with a multiplication involved in integral.

Answer (score 0):

I would compute this via the following.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with pdf's $f_X(x)= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and $f_Y(y)= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$ respectively. Then, the joint distribution would be:
$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right) \left(2 \sqrt{y}\right)}.$$
We wish to find the density of $S=X+Y$. One way to do this is to find $P(S\leq s)=P\left(X+Y\leq s\right)$ (i.e., the cdf), which turns out to be

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 F(s) = \left \{
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & s\geq 2 \\
 \frac{\pi  s}{4} & s\leq 1 \\
 \sqrt{s-1}+\frac{1}{2} z \left(\csc ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{s}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{s-1}\right)\right) & 1 < s < 2\\
\end{array}
\right.
 \\
\end{array}.$$

Differentiating, we get the density

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 f(s) = \left \{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\pi }{4} & s<1 \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{z-1}}-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{s}} \sqrt{s}}-\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{s-1}\right)+\csc ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{s}\right)\right) & 1<s<2 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\right.
\end{array}$$

We can verify the density is correct by integrating over the domain of support and make sure it sums to 1, which it does as shown below.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\pi }{4} \, dz+\int_1^2 \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{z-1}}-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z}} \sqrt{z}}-\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{z-1}\right)+\csc ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)\right) \, dz = 1$$

To compute $P(S \leq 1)$, we can use the cdf or the pdf - whatever. It turns out that
$$P(S \leq 1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
as you can see by examining the cdf or integrating the pdf.

Comment: Excellent! Just wondered, how did you manage to get $F(s)$?

Comment: HINT: To compute the cdf of $S = X + Y$, simply use the definition of the cdf, evaluating each case by double integrating the joint density
over the subset of the support set corresponding to $\{(x,y\}: x + y \leq S\}$, for different cases depending on the value of $s$. I.e., $F(z) = P(s \leq S) = P(X + Y \leq s)$. Does that make sense?